# NSDictionary or custom NSObject for JSON parsing

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, nsdictionary, nsobject

I've seen a lot of people use `NSDictionary` for JSON parsing:

```
//ViewController.m
NSString* forename = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"forename"];
NSString* surname = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"surname"];
```

But I've also people creating custom `NSObject`s from a `NSDictionary`.

```
//JSONObject.h
@interface JSONObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString* forename;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* surname;
@end

//JSONObject.m
@implementation JSONObect

@synthesize forename = _forename;
@synthesize surname = _surname;

@end

//ViewController.m
JSONObject* jsonObject = [[JSONObject alloc] init];
[jsonObject setForename:[jsonDict valueForKey:@"forename"]];
[jsonObject setSurname:[jsonDict valueForKey:@"surname"]];
```

And then store these in a `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSMutableArray* jsonObjectsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
[jsonObjectsArray addObject:jsonObject];
```

Which can be accessed later if needed.

In my case, I have a `UITableView` that gets it's data from JSON. The data is used at least once but most likely will be used more (eg. on device rotation). The JSON data shouldn't be permanently stored to file as it is updated regularly and is downloaded every time the app launches.

Should I use a custom `NSObject` or a `NSDictionary` in my scenario?

Comment: I made the question sound more of a discussion question rather than Q&A, hopefully my edit made it a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

One argument for using a custom Object is that it is a few short steps away from using a NSManagedObject, which would let you leverage Core Data to manage your object graph.

Comment: The custom object is also arguably more compact in storage.

Answer (score 0):

The argument for using the NSDictionary is that it's simpler and easier to understand, and you define fewer "minor" classes (and associated h/m files), so less to manage in a project.  Also a lot easier to edit/extend in a project "in flux".